# How to debug project compiled with gcc in VS?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, gcc, fortran

I have DLL project (wrote in fortran, C++) compiled with gcc. I would like to debug this DLL but I have to attach to process running on Windows (compiled in Visual Studio). I can't insert breakpoints in Visual Studio to DLL sources. 
Please could you help me someone?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. For starters the debug information format generated by GCC is not the same as the one used by Visual Studio. To continue, Visual Studio have no idea what Fortran is, and so would not be able to do anything useful with the debug information anyway as it would not be able to use the source.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a break point into source code Visual Studio, and really any debugger, has to find a way to map the source lines to address ranges in the executable code.  Visual Studio uses the PDB format to create this type of mapping.  This file is generated during build time for all languages in Visual Studio.  gcc though does not produce this file and hence there is really no way for Visual Studio to map source lines from the file to meaningful values in the generated executable

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://www.wingdb.com/

Apart from that, the easiest way is to rebuild the code using Visual Studio since you have the source.  You can get IVF on one month evaluation and use it to generate the DLL and pdb files.  If it works and you like IVF, ask your bosses to get you a copy.

Another alternative is to use ddd in a Linux environment.  Just create a Linux VM on your Windows machine, rebuild everything for Linux, get ddd and you're away.